# Trigger Based Replication (Live Sync) OR Transactional Replication in MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

can someone give me a clear idea about which technique/ method is more reliable, less memory consuming and faster in replicating data from one Database to another in ***MSSQL database(SQl Server 2012)*** and why. We are in the process of developing a Live GPS based tracking application and I am confused with which method to proceed with

1. **Trigger Based Replication (Live Sync)**
   (OR)
2. **Transactional Replication**

   Thanks in Advance ☺

Comment: Are you limited with the options listed? If so, why these?

Comment: @Roger Wolf : Yes I am limited with the above options since I use a MS SQL database where standard replication methods like transactional, snapshot and merge replication are available apart from the technique trigger based sync between two databases. If there happens to other replication methods apart from these plz help me with them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using standardised solutions whenever possible. Within the choice given to you, transaction replication should be an obvious favourite, because:

1. It doesn't require any coding and can be deployed using standard tools. This makes it much faster to deploy and maintain - any proper DBA can do it, some of them even being blindfolded.
2. Actual data transfer is done by replication agents which are separate applications external to the SQL Server process and client connections. Any network issues within the publisher-distributor-subscriber(s) chain will lead to delays in copying the data, but they will not affect the performance of the publisher database itself.

With triggers, you have neither of these advantages: you will have to add a lot of code, and sluggish network will make data-changing queries slower, potentially leading to timeouts.

Of course, there are many more ways to move the data between the databases in SQL Server, such as (in no particular order):

- AlwaysOn Availability Groups (Database mirroring);
- Log shipping;
- CDC (Change Data Capture);
- Service Broker.

However, given your needs, transaction replication still looks like your best bet, overall.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you gave a clear picture to choose whats best. However I have one more query : say both the **source and the destination databases are on the same server**, in this case would Transactional replication still be the right choice in terms of performance considering the fact that **network related risks are eliminated ?**

Comment: @PraveenKumar, it's not just network. With triggers your databases become tightly coupled, and any issue with the target (waits on transaction log, disk delays, etc.) will immediately affect the primary db performance. Any error in the trigger will rollback the statement that fired it. And one day databases might become separated, and then... But of course, you can go out and play with fire.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. It helped me a lot ☺